# JPA @PersistenceContext EJB EntityManager

Tags: ejb, ejb-3.0

i created an entity class from database.
now i created an EJB in which i write

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
@Startup
public class MyTester {

@PersistenceContext(name="(name = "com.mycompany_MyJPAEE_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
private EntityManager emf;    

@PostConstruct
public void myMain() {
    System.out.println("Testing");
}
```

}

But this is getting exception 
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : zoodb__pm
com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : zoodb__pm 
zoodb is my database name

Comment: Is there a persistence.xml which describes zoodb__pm?  Could you post that?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_MyJPAEE_ejb_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>zoodb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>

Comment: Yes persistence is added